# Combine two stores with React and Zustang

Tags: zustand

I'm trying to combine two stores using **Zustand**. I would like to see if it is possible to use the **Zustand/Zundo** library only on `createSelectionStore`. Combining two stores seems like a good enough solution and after some searching, I found this [issue](https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand/issues/228). So I tried to implement it in this code:

```
import { create } from 'zustand'
import { temporal } from 'zundo'

const createSelectionStore = create((set) => ({
    selected: [], // selected path indexes
    select: (index) =>
        ...
    deselect: () =>
        ...
}))

const createBikePathStore = create((set) => ({
    paths: [],
    visible: false,
    setPaths: (paths) =>
        ...
    setVisible: (visible) =>
        ...
}))

const useBikePathStore = create((set) => ({
    ...createSelectionStore(set),
    ...createBikePathStore(set),
}))

export default useBikePathStore
```

However for some reason I get some errors:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This issue is solved [here](https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand/discussions/1854)

I was miss using slices pattern https://docs.pmnd.rs/zustand/guides/slices-pattern